# How many queries does google allow from a specified IP or website?

Tags: php, seo

I have made a PHP script that counts the no. of back-links from Google of a given website. But my dilemma is how many queries can I perform(as Google has a limit to that)? kindly answer my question and give some solution as soon as possible.

Comment: make sure whatever you do doesn't break Google's terms of service.

Comment: @Spudley There is no way that scraping Google (if that is indeed what the OP is doing) is not a violation of their ToS.

Answer (score 4):

This depends on the speed of requests... you can send thousands of queries from a single ip but you need to do this like a human (slow), not like a bot which sends 20 or so queries every second.

I have done a similar script for myself and the only solution for    this are:

- use the [google search api](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview?hl=de#Pricing), which will costs you    something.

or

- scrape google like you did but use [proxies](http://bit.ly/anonymous-proxies). (which will also
  cost you something, i don't recommend free proxies because they are slow and can change the content)

or

- use a captcha solving service to automatically unblock the google captcha.

Comment: qxxx thanks for answering .but what if i make a database of websites and then automatically run the script  with a given interval of time .will it work?

Comment: you could create a script which will grab the url from the database and check it. Run the script every minute and it should work fine (cron). So you can check 60*24 = 1440 urls in a day. You could also try to check 2 or more urls in 1 call but use the sleep function to wait for at least 10 seconds between new check.